# Best way to design the site for Internet Explorer 7 and before

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When developing a website that has a rich user interface we end up with problems with the Internet Explorer.

What is the best way to work on IE, should we have a separate css only designated for IE.

Comment: This is a large topic, and the only answer is: it depends. You need to give a lot more information about what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You need to read about IE Conditional Comments: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Aroha Labs is in Karachi right? I had come there once I remember :)

Comment: You can try [SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SuperPreview_Overview.aspx), a tool by Microsoft for testing browser compatibility.

Comment: thanks for the help, i'll try the conditional comments n super preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE6 if it's readable, it's ok (no shadow and little details, it's for old computer), for IE7, IE8 respect the layout, for IE9 it's more easy.
You can look at http://modernizr.com/ and tutorial about this script for best usage.

Comment: Can Modernizer tell what it fixed, i used modernizer and it resolved 80% of the problems .. but well i still want to know what is the reason, what did modernizer fix?, in case i dont want to use modernizer

Answer (score 1):

Consider using separate isolated simplified stylesheet for old IE versions. For example, [Universal Internet Explorer 6 CSS](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/).